# as3 draw line with LineStyle and then edit with transparent (invisible) pixels

Tags: actionscript-3

I have MC with external loaded image (jpg).

Next layer is masked Sprite where I am drawing lines in different colors, opacity ,etc with graphics.lineStyle . Everything works fine, so I can see image and drawings over. Now I want eraser to make, and trying to make some kind of (transparent) line which will "erase" exising line.

If I for example draw (with mouse) red line, and then switch color to yellow and intersect on some point with previous line, it is ok, I see yellow color. Now I don't have idea how to make "transparent" color? So when mouse move over existing drawing, just see again part of background image. If I set one color background everything is OK, but I have image, end eraser leaves some color, and I need to be transparent. Tried blend modes, cached as bmp, everything I found but still no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seemingly you use Graphics objects that overlay the image. In order to erase something, you should give your sprite a topmost shape that will have BlendMode.ERASE as blend mode, and draw on it with alpha component of color being 0xFF. The sprite should have its blendMode to be BlendMode.LAYER. Here's a test to play with:

```
public class TestErase extends Sprite 
{
    public function TestErase() {
        var b:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var c:Shape = new Shape();
        b.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
        c.blendMode = flash.display.BlendMode.ERASE;
        c.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);
        c.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
        c.graphics.endFill();
        b.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
        b.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
        b.graphics.endFill();
        b.addChild(c);
        addChild(b);
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x00c000, 1);
        graphics.drawRect(75, 75, 100, 100);
        graphics.endFill();

    }
}
```

This makes a 50x50 hole, defined by "c" sprite in "b" sprite, that does not affect "this" sprite.

Okay you asked for an example. Here.

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public var sh:Shape;
    public var drawing:Boolean;
    public var sp:Sprite;
    public var bd:BitmapData;
    public var erasing:Boolean;
    [Embed(source = '../lib/093.jpg')]
    public static const Background:Class;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
        var ba:Bitmap = new Background();
        ba.scaleX = 0.5;
        ba.scaleY = 0.5;
        addChild(ba);
        bd = new BitmapData(640, 400, true, 0);
        var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
        sp = new Sprite();
        sp.addChild(bm);
        sp.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
        var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        tf.y = 401;
        tf.background = true;
        tf.backgroundColor = 0x0;
        tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Arial', 12, 0xe00000, true, false, false);
        tf.selectable = false;
        tf.text = 'Erase';
        addChild(tf);
        addChild(sp);
        tf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleErasing);
        sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
        sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, endDrawing);
        sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrawing);
    }

    private function toggleErasing(e:MouseEvent):void {
        erasing = !erasing;
        if (erasing) (e.currentTarget as TextField).text = 'Erasing...'; else (e.currentTarget as TextField).text = 'Erase';
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    private function startDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (drawing) return;
        sh = new Shape();
        sh.graphics.lineStyle(3, Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x100000), 1,true);
        if (erasing) sh.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
        sh.graphics.moveTo(e.localX, e.localY);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, trackMouse);
        sp.addChild(sh);
        drawing = true;
    }
    private function endDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (!drawing) return;
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, trackMouse);
        if (erasing) bd.draw(sh, null, null, BlendMode.ERASE); 
        else  bd.draw(sh);
        sp.removeChild(sh);
        sh = null;
        drawing = false;
    }
    private function trackMouse(e:MouseEvent):void {
        sh.graphics.lineTo(e.localX, e.localY);
    }

}
```

Tested by me, and should work as is, just change the background :)

Comment: This make sense, thanks! But still can't reach what I am trying. You are right: I am trying to use Graphic object that overlay image. But when I change tool from "drawing" to "eraser" with instructions/code you wrote, I get whole drawing desepear like when I use lineStyle.clear(), any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should use a separate layer to draw with eraser, because changing blendMode changes behavior of the entire layer, which most likely consists of one object in your program. Also, in order to draw above the eraser, you will need another layer of graphics. The trick is, the Graphics object draws itself via series of commands, and when you apply your eraser, this set of commands is unaffected, as it's not this easy to manipulate it. So each time you actually draw with eraser, you will have to add eraser layer, and each subsequent time you draw normally, you have to add another normal layer.

Comment: Sounds complicated, is there any way to convert to BitmapData and than do on easier way?

Comment: Yes, after each iteration you use a draw() of your resultant Graphics object over a transparent Bitmap object that overlays your image, and dispose that graphics (drop it as unneeded). You will start afresh each time, but your precision will be limited to a single pixel of the layered bitmap.

Comment: Maybe worth to try. You helped a lot and thanks for your time. Can I ask for some nice example? :) Would that be too much? :)

Comment: Hmmm. You need to know when you start drawing and when you end drawing. When you end drawing, you do like this: You just have a Graphics object with all parameters set, you plain do YourBitmapData.draw(YourGraphics); and then discard YourGraphics, and at the start of your next drawing, you create another YourGraphics and draw there.

Comment: If you're only watching comments, please check for the updated answer.

Comment: Vesper i am testing this solution, it seems will work as I need, so big thanks for You!