# adding transparent sprite over another sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to place a transparent sprite over another sprite. The overlaying sprite will acept some mouse events. When a user move mouse over upper sprite a curve will be drawn. After it'll be processed it will be drawn on the base sprite (and erased on upper).

The idea I have now is to place the sprite, draw a rectange of size equal to sizes of sprite and set alpha to 0.

The question is a bit dump: maybe the proposed solution is not the best. Is there a better way to set width and height (as far a I understand `Sprite.width = w;` will not help)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why can't you set this mouse eventos on the sprite itself?

Comment: Well, that's not possible for me. I've updated the question: When a user move mouse over upper sprite a curve will be drawn. After it'll be processed it will be drawn on the base sprite (and erased on upper).

Comment: What you are doing is correct. You can't set the width or height of a Sprite. It takes the dimension of the bounding rectangle of its content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set dimensions directly, while you can draw over that Sprite. So you can do like this:

```
graphics.beginFill(0,0); // zero alpha fill
graphics.lineStyle(0,0,0); // invisible lines
graphics.drawRect(0,0,width,height);
graphics.endFill();
```

This way your Sprite can have its alpha remaining at 1, to not hide anything that's its child. Then, whatever curve you would decide to draw in that Sprite, you can draw within a child Shape object, via graphics.moveTo and graphics.lineTo.

UPDATE: According to comments below, setting alpha to 0 won't work with newer Flash player versions, so alpha should be set to a nonzero amount for the events to register on the overlapping sprite.

```
graphics.beginFill(0x808080,0.01); // almost zero alpha fill
```

Comment: Well, that's what I called: The idea I have now is to place the sprite, draw a rectange of size equal to sizes of sprite and set alpha to 0. Anyway thank you!

Comment: No, there's more. With this approach you can have more things drawn over the sprite, which would not be fully transparent. Say, you have a moving shape within that Sprite of yours. With your approach (set alpha to 0) that shape will too be invisible, with this approach only that rectangle drawn within the sprite will be invisible, nothing else. Anyway, if you just need a rectangle that would react to mouse events, you can use either approach.

Comment: Check this for some reference: [How to draw over a Sprite without it getting laggier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143171/as3-draw-line-with-linestyle-and-then-edit-with-transparent-invisible-pixels/12143511#12143511) (This didn't fit in the previous comment, sorry for double post)

Comment: Any ideas why with the beginFill set to alpha 0 I don't get touch events fired on that sprite? :/

Comment: @ThatMarc Maybe newer Flash players have a solution similar to browser's "ClearClick", that is, newer Flash player explicitly checks if the object with a listener is fully transparent there and plain doesn't register the event. Check if you set alpha to a small amount (0.05, maybe 0.01 would also work) and check if your sprite would receive events. If not, set alpha to 1 and check if the sprite is actually visible.

Comment: I've ended up with just that - alpha to 0.01 which made it basically transparent but still clickable. I suppose the newer flash has something to do with that, yes, as my collegues all told me "I've done this before, it must work". Or it has something to do with the fact I also have window and chrome swt to transparent/none. Basically I want to fire events when you have literally no idea that the air is even running... :) either way, solved now. Thanks!